# How can I get a Django template to use string formatting?

Tags: python, django, string, formatting

I want the events.html template to format the string somehow, but I do not know how I would do that.  The way I have it below is how I would think it should work, but it doesn't.

events.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for object in objects %}
<h1>{{object.name}}</h1>
<p>When: {{ "It will take place in the year %s and the month %s" % (object.when.year, object.when.month) }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
import pdb
from events.models import Event

def home(request):
    objects = Event.objects.all()
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'events.html', {'objects': objects});
```

Comment: Does it throw an error? If not, what is the output? And are `object.when.year` and `object.where.month` both integers?

Comment: "Could not parse the remainder" I'm assuming it's treating the "%" as a modulo operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why interpolate when you don't need to? Try the following:

```
<p>When: It will take place in the year {{ object.when.year }} and the month {{ object.when.month }}</p>
```

Another thought: regarding your string interpolation, [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-codeyou%20sh) say the following:

> For this reason, you should use named-string interpolation (e.g., %(day)s) instead of positional interpolation (e.g., %s or %d) whenever you have more than a single parameter. If you used positional interpolation, translations wouldn’t be able to reorder placeholder text.

So, first off, you need to enclose the arguments to be interpolated as a *dict*, which dictates that they're enclosed in curly brackets, not parentheses as you have in your code. Then, you should use named parameters, rather than relying on positional interpolation.

```
{{ "It will take place in the year %(year) and the month %(month)." % {'year': objects.when.year, 'month': objects.when.month} }}
```

Comment: Well, I guess for this example I didn't really need to, but I thought it would be useful to know how to.  But I didn't really think of doing it the basic way, I guess I'm tired..

Comment: Fair enough. In addition to my initial suggestion, I've provided an explanation for what went wrong in your original code. If it helps, please consider [accepting this answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).